# Can I run Linux on specific CPU cores?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, devices, embedded, multithreading

I'm making a brainwave detection device. 
Will be using an Octa-Core ARM processor for the software processing.
For the management of CPU cores, can I code Linux to strictly run on a specific set of cores? Let's say core 1, 2, and 3. 
But it should not be too strict as I also need to spawn the device driver on a separate core (let's take core 4). 
So is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can specify the number of supported cores in the kernel configuration and build a custom kernel. If that would suffice, of course. There is no CPU mask for the kernel so I have no idea on what cores the kernel will end up running.

Answer (score 2):

You can isolate CPU cores, so that the kernel scheduler will ignore them, using either the `isolcpus` [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html), or [CPU sets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html).

Thus booting your kernel with

```
isolcpus=4-7
```

will leave cores 5 to 8 for your own purposes; you’d need to manually schedule your processes there using thread affinity.

I don’t think it’s possible to dedicate a CPU core to a driver in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit a process to certain cores:

```
taskset mask command [arguments]
```

Comment: What about restricting the Linux Kernel to specific set of cores?

Comment: @MiteshG At least I am not aware of such possibilities. You could run Linux in a VM, though, and limit the VM process to certain cores. This may not be attractive in the context of writing device drivers, though.

Comment: If userspace code is running on core N, then whenever it does a syscall, the kernel will be running on core N.  So you would have to disable the core entirely.